# change highlight color in interface

Tags: interface

How do I change the highlight color of my blender interface?
I tried Preferences>Editing>Anotation>Default color. But that didn't help.[image]

Comment: Hello :). *Editing > Annotations > Default color* only affects the *Annotate Tool* default color. I added a full answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Highlight colors can be set in *Preferences > Themes > User Interface*.
You can set different highlight colors for different parts of UI.

In this case, it's the *Menu Item > Selected*

[image]

To change color for other items, go through the *User Interface* list.
Or download a theme :).

Comment: Thank you very much!!